# onmouseover,onmouseout javascript not working in google chrome

Tags: javascript

onmouseover,onmouseout javascript not working in google chrome.properly working in mozila.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleMe(id) {
    var image = document.getElementById(id);
    if(id.style.display == "block") {
        id.style.display = "none";
    } else {
        id.style.display = "block";
    }
}
</script>

<div onmouseover="toggleMe(<?php echo "I".$id; ?>)" onmouseout="toggleMe(<?php echo "I".$id; ?>)">
    <?php echo $result_v['model_name']; ?>
</div>
<img src="<?php echo $result_v['image']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $result_v['model_name']; ?>" id="<?php echo "I".$id; ?>" class="imagebox" />
```

Comment: Seeing as you're passing strings to your `toggleMe` function, the arguments should be quoted, ie `toggleMe("I<?= $id ?>")`. You should be checking your console for errors.

Comment: there is no syntax iessue with my code its properly working in mozila but not working in google chrome.

Comment: Some browsers will automatically create variable references for ID'd elements. Chrome is **not** one of these browsers. Write your code properly

Answer (score 1):

Two problems, unquoted strings in the calls to your function. Fix like this...

```
<div onmouseover="toggleMe('I<?= $id ?>')"...
<!-- note the quotes       ^           ^ -->
```

Second, you are using the wrong reference in your function to access the `style` property. It should be `image`, ie

```
if(image.style.display == "block") {
    image.style.display = "none";
} else {
    image.style.display = "block";
}
```

All that being said, I'd just use data attributes instead of injecting strings into JavaScript functions...

```
<div data-image="I<?= $id ?>" onmouseover="toggleMe(this)"...
```

and the function

```
function toggleMe(trigger) {
    var image = document.getElementById(trigger.getAttribute('data-image'));
    image.style.display = image.style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block';
}
```

Comment: after using your code there is no result in mozila also plz help me..